# Using "this.prototype" vs outer "Constructor.prototype" in OOP

Tags: javascript, oop, syntax, prototype

In JavaScript, defining a classlike (constructor) function method is usually done like this:

```js
function Class1() {
   // ... code ...
}
Class1.prototype.method1 = function(args) {
   // ... code ...
};
```

And going by the general syntax/semantics rules of ECMAScript, there is no reason I couldn't override/alter/extend the original Object.prototype with

```js
function Class1() {
   // ... code ...
   this.prototype.method1 = function(args) {
      // ... code ...
   };
}
```

Then why is it not done that way? Code would look a bit more confusing, but a lot quicker and cleaner to write and read (putting all Class1-related methods right underneath Class1 itself). Wouldn't it be a better use?

Comment: Your second sample code will not work. The value of `this` inside the constructor is *not* the constructor function; it's the value of the newly-created object.

Comment: Then could I access it via `this.constructor`? I might as well edit my question to that.

Comment: The constructor runs for *every* object instantiated. You're adding a new set of identical functions to your prototype every single time you you build a new object, which has pretty huge performance implications.

Comment: I strongly suggest you look into the [augment](https://github.com/javascript/augment) project.  Even if you don't use the library, the code is a great way to learn about how this stuff works.

Comment: For an explanation about prototype and constructor functions I have created this answer, hope it helps.http://stackoverflow.com/a/16063711/1641941

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two pieces of code are most definitely **not** the same; the second one won't work.

What happens in the constructor (usually) has nothing to do with the prototype object. It's initialization code for each instance. The "prototype" property of interest is the "prototype" property of the constructor function, not of the instances.

Creating prototype functions inside the constructor doesn't make sense, because it'd mean you'd be re-doing that work for each instance you create.

Comment: Right, I guess I get it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is those two code samples are not equivalent. In the first example 'this' refers to Class1, but in the second example 'this' refers to whatever that newly created object was. For example,

```
var myObj = new Class1()
```

in the example above, 'this' is myObj - which breaks your second example.

Also, even if that did work, you would be then recreating that method for every instance you made. It would be much more efficient to not do that.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers have pointed out, the second use of prototype is not a valid javascript code, but it seems you want to have access to your constructor when it is actually running, which is possible with these 2 options:

1- if you don't use strict mode, you can have it like:

```
  var MyClass = function ClassConstructor(){
         arguments.callee.prototype. ...
  }
```

2- in strict mode for instance if you have your classlike function like:

```
var MyClass = function ClassConstructor(){
        ClassConstructor.prototype. ...
 }
```

this way you can use ClassConstructor only in the constructor, it is kind of private there.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you fix the code, to point to the correct `this`, prototypical properties are added to each instance, when they're created.

But they're added by sharing the same copy of the method/property.

If it wasn't called prototype: if it was called "Bob" and copied by hand, it would make more sense:

```
var Bob = {
    name : "Bob",
    sayName: function ( ) {
         var person = this;
         console.log( "My name is " + person.name );
    }
};



 var Person = function (name) {
    var person = this;
    person.name = name || Bob.name;
    person.sayName = Bob.sayName;
 };


var doug = new Person("Doug"),
    jim  = new Person("Jim");
```

There are a couple of things going on behind the scenes, regularly, but there really isn't much difference here, between `Bob` and what would normally be `Person.prototype`.

But you can clearly see why you wouldn't want to reset Bob.name, every single time you make a new person.